# Generate dynamic css classes in laravel-blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm in a classical scenario where i want based on wheter an error has occurred or not to change the css classes. As shown below, where has-error should change accordingly.

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
```

The project is in Laravel, where we mainly want to do everything in `Blade` as of now, we came up with the following solution which works, but does not look pretty or intuitive at all, so the question is, is there a more optimal way of doing this?

```
<div class="form-group
@if($errors->has('email'))
        has-error
@endif
">
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try the if else condition short hand code:

```
<form class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
```

This seems neat.

Even the Laravel 5.2 auth forms are done this way.

Comment: Neat tryed a similar apporach, but the compiler kept puking at me, will try this version when i get to the office, thanks this is definetly in the range of pretty enough

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of arrays to store the class names

```
@php
$formGroupClasses = ['form-group'];

if ($errors->has('email')) {
  $formGroupClasses[] = 'has-error';
}
@endphp
```

and then implode them to create a string

```
<form class="{{ implode(' ', $formGroupClasses) }}">
```

Answer (score 2):

That's what I do. You could also do it that way:

```
@if($errors->has('email'))
    <div class="form-group has-error"> 
       //You can also edit classes of other elements 
    </div>
@else
    <div class="form-group"></div>
@endif
```

Comment: Also the same conclusion i came up with, but missing an ng-class like AngularJS has.